# What are the Sysadmin-Related Blogs & Mailing Lists you monitor?

Tags: untagged

I know this is a gimme question, but I genuinely would like to add more sysadmin related feeds to my reader, so please list the contents of your feedreader.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/580 is a dupe, but has some good alternative answers.

Answer (score 17):

Blackhat SEO

- http://contempt.me/ - Totally a jerk, possibly illegal.  Blog spam, spam rings, and the like.  But an interesting look into administration of hundreds or thousands of tiny sites.

Scaling

- http://highscalability.com/ - Often about code, but just as often about scaling servers and system tweaks to optimize.  Like [this article](http://highscalability.com/strategy-facebook-tweaks-handle-6-time-many-memcached-requests) and optimizing even CPU load balancing

Security

- http://gentoo-portage.com/GLSA - Because I run gentoo.  The security list of whatever major products you use is standard I think
- http://xorl.wordpress.com/ - He reads the patches for security holes and shows where the error is.  It's code, but often in the kernel or major packages
- http://www.darknet.org.uk/ - Often has posts about tools, including forensics, SCADA, and the like
- http://digg.com/security - Often fluff or several days behind, but it's slow-moving so it's easy to stick in and forget
- http://ha.ckers.org/blog/ - More configuration type posts, but also talks about large-scale deployment of security fixes and techniques
- http://www.net-security.org/ - I find this to be almost total fluff and markest more at CIOs looking for buzzwords, but once in a while some signal gets through
- http://www.net-security.org/insecuremag.php - An awesome magazine that comes out every few months
- http://jeremiahgrossman.blogspot.com/ - He runs a Web Application Firewall company, so his posts are often focused around that, numbers relating to the industry, and general Web Security
- http://www.schneier.com/blog/ - A mainstay
- http://www.secguru.com/ - Something like a reddit for security.  It often gets good articles but some of then are fluff
- http://www.windowsecurity.com/ - Has good tutorials and explanations for setting up things like Domain Authentication and Kerberos in Windows.
- http://seclists.org/#bugtraq - I monitor this for anything interesting or apps I run.  Often gets first-reports
- http://seclists.org/#dailydave - A very high signal to noise ratio list run by Dave Aitel
- http://seclists.org/#pen-test - Low signal to noise, but I skim it anyway
- http://seclists.org/#basics - Low signal to noise, but I skim it anyway.  I can actually answer some of these!
- http://seclists.org/#webappsec - Low signal to noise, but I skim it anyway

Answer (score 5):

Just one from me - I follow afp548.com for Mac OS X admin news. There are also some good mailing lists for OS X sysadmins, such as `macos-x-server@lists.apple.com` and `macenterprise@lists.psu.edu`.

Answer (score 3):

From a Windows Sys. Admin. perspective:

- [Windows Security Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowssecurity/default.aspx)
- [Windows 7 Team Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windows7/default.aspx)
- [Engineering Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/default.aspx)
- [Mark Russionovic's Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/default.aspx)
- [The Windows Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/)
- [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Planet Sysadmin](http://planetsysadmin.com/)

**Great aggregation of sysadmin blogs.**

[SAGE Mailing List](http://www.sage.org)

**Killer advice and discussion from experienced sysadmins.**

[LOPSA Discuss](http://lopsa.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/discuss)

**The US League of Professional Sysadmins general discussion list.**

[O'Reilly Radar](http://radar.oreilly.com/operations/)

**Some great sysadmin content here with a dedicated Operations stream - plenty of 21st Century sysadmin material to enjoy and think about.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a big aggregation of sysadmin blogs at planet sysadmin:

http://planetsysadmin.com/

Answer (score 1):

VM side of sysadmin stuff:

//yellow-bricks.com/

//blog.scottlowe.org/

//vmprofessional.com/

Answer (score 1):

Some of my favorite sysadmin/operations/IT blogs:

- [Kitchen Soap](http://www.kitchensoap.com/) - by John Allspaw, former Flickr's Operations Manager, now at Etsy
- [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) - Building bigger, faster, more reliable websites
- [Standalone Sysadmin](http://www.standalone-sysadmin.com/blog/) - Great tips by [Matt Simmons](https://serverfault.com/users/4392/matt-simmons) :)
- [Agile WebOperations](http://www.agileweboperations.com/) - bridging the deployment gap
- [Twitter Engineering](http://engineering.twitter.com/) - Twitter folks on Technology
- [NixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/) - Linux tips and howtos
- [MySQL Performance Blog](http://mysqlperformanceblog.com) - Best MySQL blog around
- [dev2ops](http://dev2ops.org/) - Delivering change

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with Active Directory: [ActiveDir](http://www.activedir.org/MailingList/tabid/59/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

fedora-devel-list@redhat.com -- especially enjoying to read threads where Lennart Poettering starts a round dance.

Answer (score 0):

For security-related:

http://taosecurity.blogspot.com

http://blog.sucuri.net

http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec (some good stuff)