# Best Information Technology Blogs

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Sysadmin-Related Blogs & Mailing Lists you monitor?](https://serverfault.com/questions/502/what-are-the-sysadmin-related-blogs-mailing-lists-you-monitor)

Are there any great IT blogs out there?

Which would you recommend from basic to advance stuff?

Comment: Dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my rss blogroll list:

- [The Lazy Admin](http://feeds2.feedburner.com/thelazyadmin)
- [Virtual PC Guy](http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/rss.xml)
- [Ask the Admin](http://feeds2.feedburner.com/askTheAdmin?format=xml)
- [4Sysops](http://feeds.4sysops.com/4sysops?format=xml)
- [Bink.nu](http://feeds.bink.nu/binkdotnu)
- [SysAdmin Tools](http://systemadmintools.blogspot.com/rss.xml)

and you cant go past: [XKCD](http://www.xkcd.com)

Answer (score 19):

[Mark Russinovich](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/)'s blog is very technical and comes highly recommended. You'll learn a lot about how Windows **actually** works including lots of examples of troubleshooting difficult real world problems.

Mark explores (and solves) lots of problems that many would explain by saying things like 'Windows slows down if you've had it installed for a long time'. Those same people will then tell you that reinstalling / rebooting is the best solution.

Comment: That is a great blog, though it would be nice if he updated more frequently!

Answer (score 13):

[http:www.thedailywtf.com](http://http:www.thedailywtf.com)

Answer (score 13):

[Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/) to find out why Windows is the way it is; some of the content is very developer-technical in C and over my head, but much of it isn't.

The Official Microsoft blog from your product teams - [Exchange](http://msexchangeteam.com/), [Word](http://blogs.msdn.com/microsoft_office_word/), [ISA](http://blogs.technet.com/isablog/), [SBS](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/), etc.

For malware, [Graham Cluley](http://www.sophos.com/blogs/gc) is excellent

Comment: Raymond Chen has incredible insight to the fundamentals of Windows. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 5):

[**/.**](http://slashdot.org/)

Answer (score 5):

[Robert X. Cringely](http://www.cringely.com/)  -IT Industry commentary

[Dilbert Blog](http://dilbert.com/blog/) - sometimes IT, very funny

Comment: Cringley is more of a global insight reporter.  I love his postings, but they are more of a speculation based on facts rather then a general IT blog.

Answer (score 5):

Not a blog, but an excellent source of the same type of information

[Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/)

Need more linux answers to this question too...

Answer (score 4):

For SQLServer see [Brent Ozar](http://www.brentozar.com/)

Comment: Brent is already making name for himself here on SF http://serverfault.com/users/431/brent-ozar

Answer (score 4):

http://blogs.technet.com/askds/default.aspx - MS Directory Services blog, useful for DFS and file related information

http://www.istartedsomething.com/ - Not so much IT Admin, as general Windows/computing news, but a good resources.

http://news.zdnet.com/ - Opinion articles may not be agreeable, but usually a good source of news.

Answer (score 4):

How is [Joel On Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/) not listed so far? Given his close association with this site!

Comment: but his blog is more about the software, not really IT-related.

Comment: not always, his posts about beauricracy and how a good it team should work are applicable to everyone.

Comment: didn't he quit that blog recently though?

Comment: Not entirely, its focus changed a few months ago.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I've recently become hooked on the [Security Now](http://www.grc.com/securitynow.htm) podcast.

Comment: I like the content but I want to smack Leo Laporte

Answer (score 2):

Not a blog per se, but hacker news has an awesome collection of posts (voted by the users).

http://news.ycombinator.com

Answer (score 2):

In no particular order:

- [Scott Lowe's blog](http://blog.scottlowe.org/) is quite specialized to Virtualization and enterprise storage but it's excellent in that niche.
- [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) is an aggregator of all things massively scaled, not much content there that won't appear in other places but it does bring it all together in one RSS feed.
- [Bitdroppings](http://bitdrop.st0w.com/) is good, low traffic though.
- [Matasano Chargen](http://www.matasano.com/log/) is extremely focused on security and pen testing but it's fantastically well written.
- [Max Indelicato's blog](http://blog.maxindelicato.com/) on 'distributed, scalable, software systems design and development.'

Answer (score 2):

For security: [Home Of PaulDotCom Security Podcast](http://pauldotcom.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There's the mother of all IT blogs: http://planetsysadmin.com/

There's Anton Chuvakin's Security Warrior Blog: http://chuvakin.blogspot.com/

Marcus J Ranum's site is sort of a blog and has valuable if infrequently updated information: http://www.ranum.com/

Uber Geek Brian K Jones has a blog at his amusingly named domain. It delves into mostly *nix issues. He is responsible for introducing me to and convincing me of the concept that SysAdmins should be proficient in at least one programming language: http://www.protocolostomy.com/

Bruce Schneier's blog and Crypto Gram newsletter is a must for anyone interested in security. It doesn't just focus on computer security, but a much more comprehensive thought process. Watching Schneier and Ranum face off is an enlightening experience. http://www.schneier.com/blog/

Basically, peruse the many blogs in the Planet SysAdmin blog roll. In fact, I see at least one person from that blog roll on this site. ::waves at Matt Simmons::

Comment: I'm also on planet-sysadmin. I've met Ranum and Schneier and can attest they both rawk.

Comment: Don't forget to check marcus "rear guard" security podcast http://www.rearguardsecurity.com/. It's very sincere about security and IT facts (trust, codpendence, honesty...)

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Blogs are really great across the board. A few favorites:

- [Microsoft Enterprise Networking Team](http://blogs.technet.com/networking/default.aspx)
- [Directory Services Team](http://blogs.technet.com/askds/)
- [Configuration Manager Support Team](http://blogs.technet.com/configurationmgr/)

I despise MS documentation as it's generally written in some oddball bureaucratese language with lots of circular references. I find the folks writing the blogs to be a breath of fresh air as they actually write in English.

While not a blog, I get a ton of useful info from the [Ars Technica Forums](http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums), [Ben Rockwood's blog](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/) for Sun stuff and tons of others that aren't coming to mind. Google Reader is my friend.

Answer (score 1):

For security, one of my favorites is [DarkNet.org.uk](http://www.darknet.org.uk/).

Answer (score 1):

A good Exchange blog:

http://hellomate.typepad.com/

Answer (score 1):

[joeware](http://blog.joeware.net/)

Interesting posts on some technical AD topics.

Author of adfind and admod (plus others) tools.

Answer (score 1):

Some of my favorite sysadmin/operations/IT blogs:

- [Kitchen Soap](http://www.kitchensoap.com/) - by John Allspaw, former Flickr's Operations Manager, now at Etsy
- [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) - Building bigger, faster, more reliable websites
- [Standalone Sysadmin](http://www.standalone-sysadmin.com/blog/) - Great tips by [Matt Simmons](https://serverfault.com/users/4392/matt-simmons) :)
- [Agile WebOperations](http://www.agileweboperations.com/) - bridging the deployment gap
- [Twitter Engineering](http://engineering.twitter.com/) - Twitter folks on Technology
- [NixCraft](http://www.cyberciti.biz/) - Linux tips and howtos
- [MySQL Performance Blog](http://mysqlperformanceblog.com) - Best MySQL blog around
- [dev2ops](http://dev2ops.org/) - Delivering change

Answer (score 0):

[RunAsRadio](http://www.runasradio.com) - a podcast for IT professionals. Although not a blog it still gives IT pro's a steady stream of valuable info on a variety of topics.

Answer (score 0):

- [IT Toolbox](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/IT-blogs) has a few good blogs on a variety of IT topics.
- [Compsci.ca](http://compsci.ca/blog/) can also have some good blog posts at times if you are ok with it being university students posting mostly.

Answer (score 0):

- [BNET](http://www.bnet.com/) [Bink.nu](http://bink.nu/) [Ars
  Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) [Techmeme](http://www.techmeme.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[ghacks](http://www.ghacks.net/)

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.byexamples.com

Answer (score 0):

Jurgen Appelo, NOOP.NL blogs author, published Top 100 best blogs for Developers [here](http://www.noop.nl/2009/03/top-100-blogs-for-developers-q1-2009.html). Maybe it could be useful for you.