# What is your favorite System admin reference webiste and blog?

Tags: untagged

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the Sysadmin-Related Blogs & Mailing Lists you monitor?](https://serverfault.com/questions/502/what-are-the-sysadmin-related-blogs-mailing-lists-you-monitor)

References based on 
OS, Networks , Tools (more interested in OpneSource and free but useful tools) , Scripts and Tips and Tricks

Comment: Some other duplicates: http://serverfault.com/questions/580/best-it-blogs and http://serverfault.com/questions/23349/which-websites-should-a-sys-admin-read

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at: [Best IT Blogs](https://serverfault.com/questions/580/best-it-blogs/27759#27759) (Previous Server Fault Question)

Answer (score 0):

Serverfault.com.

I started out being cheeky, but really, it's true.

When I was a Solaris admin I liked BigAdmin.  Looks like it has moved here: http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/home/index.jsp  Also sunfreeware.com was good in the day, like a freshmeat for Solaris.